# Using a proxy and disabling SSL in Tesla using Hackney adapter

Tags: erlang, elixir

Here is what I'm doing after reading the docs. I want to use this on a per module basis so this is right in the module. This approach was based on [this answer](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney/issues/633#issuecomment-637301516).

```
defmodule MyModule do
    use Tesla
    adapter Tesla.Adapter.Hackney, proxy: {"http://proxy.example.com", 5555}, ssl: {:verify, :verify_none}
```

However, I keep getting an `:nxdomain` error. The intended behaviour is for the HTTP requests to use the proxy and ignore any SSL certificate errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Here's how you set a proxy and disable SSL checks. I'm using Tesla with a Hackney adapter:

```
defmodule MyModule do
  use Tesla
  adapter Tesla.Adapter.Hackney, proxy: "https://proxy.example.com:5000", ssl_options: [verify: :verify_none]
```

If you'd like to specify the host and port separately, it will be:

```
defmodule MyModule do
  use Tesla
  adapter Tesla.Adapter.Hackney, proxy: {"https://proxy.example.com", 5000}, ssl_options: [verify: :verify_none]
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the Hackney documentation, the `proxy` option is either a simple URL or a host+port tuple.  Try changing it to either:

```
proxy: {"proxy.example.com", 5555}
```

or

```
proxy: "http://proxy.example.com:5555"
```

Comment: That's what I currently have and it's not working. I'm also trying to get both the proxy to work and the SSL checks to be disabled.